How do I get OSMDroid sample code to show map tiles after clearing the app storage?
I am following the osmdroid sample code: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library-(Kotlin). I also attempted the solution from here: osmdroid map tiles showing blank
My permissions:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

I also added android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to the application in the manifest.
My xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

My onCreate:
private lateinit var map : MapView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        getInstance().load(this, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this))
        setContentView(R.layout.main)

        map = findViewById(R.id.map)
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK)
    }

Results: The map loads at first. When I clear the app's storage, the map goes away and doesn't come back, only showing a blank grid with no tiles.
I assume it isn't invalidating the cache after I clear the app's storage?
update:
I tried checking for cache storage handling as this article suggests: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Important-notes-on-using-osmdroid-in-your-app#handling-cache-storage. I checked the result of StorageUtils.isWritable(getInstance().osmdroidTileCache) and it threw (and caught) a null pointer error: Unable to create base path at null.
update 2: I noticed in the logs this warning/error: IOException downloading MapTile: /0/0/0 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed. According to this article: OSM IO Exception downloading MapTile it's due to not having write permissions in your manifest. I do have write permissions, but my IDE is warning me, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is deprecated (and is not granted) when targeting Android 13+. So I suspect that this is the real problem

One possible issue is not setting your own "user agent" value for Osmdroid when trying to use freely available OSM maps: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Important-notes-on-using-osmdroid-in-your-app#set-the-http-user-agent-variable as there's some sort of a quota for the map tile requests and it's quickly used up if everyone uses the same "user agent".

@MarkusKauppinen I tried getInstance().userAgentValue = packageName but that didn't appear to change anything. I also tried the advice in the Handling Cache Storage section, but I'm not sure if I'm doing that correctly. I'll update the original post with more info
